# Canvas to URLData not resizing right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a problem, when I click undo on the page it makes the canvas resize smaller?
Just go to the page, draw a few things, click undo and until you have nothing, then repeat and you will see the problem, everything moves like its resizing the image? I think there must be something wrong with the currentState variable but the code makes sense in my head so I cannot see what is wrong and have nobody I know to proof read it.

http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html
Here is my code:

```
    function clearCanvas()
    {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

    }
   Stack1 = new Stack();
    ///////////////////

    function Stack() {
    var currentState = -1;
    var maxStates = 10;
     var stateArray = [];



currentState++;
var image = new Image();
image.id = "pic";
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
stateArray.push(image);




    this.add = function() {
    currentState++;
var image = new Image();
image.id = "pic";
image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
stateArray.push(image);

    }


    this.undo = function () {



    if(currentState > 0)
     {
    currentState--;

      //stateArray.pop();
      clearCanvas();
     var image = stateArray[currentState];
      ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
      }


    }

    this.redo = function () {

    alert("Unfinished");
    //maybe have another array?



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to pop the current frame in array when undo was clicked because other wise array would be adding one after the one you want.

```
 this.undo = function () {




    if(currentState < 0)
    {
    currentState = 0;
    clearCanvas();
    }
    else(curre

if(currentState >= 0)
 {

 stateArray.pop();
currentState--;


  clearCanvas();
 var image = stateArray[currentState];
  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
  }


}
```

Also for the redo function, I will add the popped frames into a new array and use them when you click redo. Might get a bit tricky however.